# [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, json

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
include("JSON.php");
$json = new Services_JSON();
$value=array('jsonrpc'=>'2.0', 'method'=>'methodname', 'params'=>array('param1',"param2"),'id'=>1);
$output = $json->encode($value);
print($output);

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept: application/json\r\n"."Content-type: application/json-rpc\r\n"."Content-Length:1000\r\n"  ,
 'user_agent'    => 'spider',
 'content'=>$output
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('link', false, $context);

print($file);
 $value = $json->decode($file);
?>
```

But I get this error:

> [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

I have tried seeing the settings in *php.ini* file, everyhting seems fine.
I tried `file_get_contents('www.google.com')` and it worked.

Comment: You should have got a 3-digit error code when it said "HTTP request failed".

Comment: What is within JSON.php? This does not look like a PHP error.

Comment: What does `var_dump($http_response_header);` directly after the `file_get_contents` say?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code you are calling:

```
$file = file_get_contents('link', false, $context);
```

Then PHP is trying to find "link" as a file. When it does not, it fails. That would be the only logical problem I see.

By the way, PHP includes json_encode/json_decode